# Numpy array from pandas dataframe

Tags: python, dataset, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I am new in using python for data science.
What is the difference between selecting a a column with: `df['name'].values` and `df.iloc[:,1].values` and `df.iloc[:,1:2].values` they return differnt types of numpy vectors. why?

Comment: assuming 'name' is the second column. they should be identical. please includes some example codes, so we can help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not entirely sure what you mean by "numpy vectors" but am assuming the question is why each of these methods return essentially (almost but not quite) the same output...

Reference: [pandas docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html).

`df['name'].values` is a "Series corresponding to colname". In other words, you're just calling the data from that column and putting the in an array by calling `.values`.

`.iloc` is a "Purely integer-location based indexing for selection by position". Same as above but you're calling the indexed location of the column where `df.iloc[:, 1]` is `df.iloc[all rows, col 2]`. Probably an easier method to call multiple consecutive columns in a DataFrame then writing out each individual column name.

`df.iloc[:,1:2].values` <-- creates an array of arrays where the main array is the column that you called (col2) and each row values is contained in a subarray. This is--I think-- because you're slicing the dataframe between column index locations 1 and 2 (rather than just calling loc 1 like above). This would mean that each row is being called individually so that a new array is created for each row that exists between column index locations 1 and 2 (which is the 'parent' array).